# sending a list of unsupported type using parceler

Tags: java, android, parcelable, parceler

I'm trying to send a List between two Activites using Parceler.  This is what i've been trying to do:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SearchServices.this, MainActivity.class);

intent.putExtra(SearchServices.PARCELER_TAG,Parcels.wrap(
                    new Services(Arrays.asList(sortedArrayr)) ));

startActivity(intent);
```

`sortedArrayr` is a valid array of `DataSnapshot`

```
Intent intent = this.getIntent();

Log.e("onCreate: ", Parcels.unwrap(intent.getParcelableExtra(SearchServices.PARCELER_TAG)).toString() );
```

Parceler class

```
@Parcel(Parcel.Serialization.BEAN)
public class Services {

    List<DataSnapshot> ser;

    public Services(List<DataSnapshot> ser) {
        this.ser = ser;
    }

    public Services() {
    }
}
```

but I keep getting a `NullPointerException`:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
```

Comment: what if you use bundle instead put it in intent extra?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Parcelable android.os.Bundle.getParcelable(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: What does `DataSnapshot` look like?  And what is "unsupported"?